# How do I ensure that the fontawesome in my web extension display when opened in Google and gmail?

Tags: javascript, html, font-awesome

The web extension I developed opens up a search input field in a modal.
The modal (with the search input field) when triggered, displays regardless of what page a user is on. The input search field has a Fontawesome icon `<i class="fa fa-search"></i>` which displays perfectly on whatever website I visit, however, I noticed it fails to show when I trigger it while in my Gmail or Google.com.

How do I ensure that the font-awesome icons display on all websites even in my Gmail or Google.com? Has Goolge got some kind of script that blocks fontawesome icons from being displayed?

Find below the contents to the `content.js` file I use to generate my search field and add the icon:

```
//Create the modal & add it to the HTML body
const modal = document.createElement('div');
modal.classList.add('modal');
modal.style.display = 'none';
modal.style.position = 'fixed';
modal.style.justifyContent = 'center';
modal.style.zIndex = '1';
modal.style.left = '0';
modal.style.top = '0';
modal.style.width = '100%';
modal.style.height = '100%';
modal.style.overflow = 'auto';
modal.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.4)';
document.body.appendChild(modal);

//Create the search container and place it inside the modal
const searchContainer = document.createElement('div');
searchContainer.classList.add('search-container');
searchContainer.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
searchContainer.style.borderRadius = '20px';
searchContainer.style.display = 'flex';
searchContainer.style.justifyContent = 'center';
searchContainer.style.marginTop = '11rem';
searchContainer.style.marginRight = '1rem';
searchContainer.style.alignItems = 'center';
searchContainer.style.position = 'relative';
searchContainer.style.width = '300px';
searchContainer.style.height = '40px';
modal.appendChild(searchContainer);

//Create the input and place it inside the search container
const searchInput = document.createElement('input');
searchInput.type = 'text';
searchInput.placeholder = 'Search...JavaScript';
searchInput.style.width = '90%';
searchInput.style.height = '100%';
searchInput.style.border = 'none';
searchInput.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
searchInput.style.color = '#6e6e6e';
searchInput.style.outline = 'none';
searchInput.style.fontSize = '16px';
searchInput.style.padding = '0px 18px 0px 18px';
searchInput.style.borderRadius = '20px';
searchContainer.appendChild(searchInput);

//add the icon inside the input
const searchIcon = document.createElement('i');
searchIcon.classList.add('fa', 'fa-search');
searchIcon.style.color = '#888';
searchIcon.style.fontSize = '20px';
searchIcon.style.position = 'absolute';
searchIcon.style.right = '10px';
searchContainer.appendChild(searchIcon);
```

Find below my `content.html` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styleForModal.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="fontawesome/fontawesome-free-6.4.0-web/css/all.min.css">
  <title>QuickDic</title>
  <script src="content.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As I understand the question you trying to write an HTML-Email or Email-template. However, you should know that emails are very picky and best support HTML4. CSS or external libraries are only supported by a small amount. The only reliable email solution is the usage of HTML4 and inline-style. Especially for security reasons, you should assume that JS is not supported in emails at all!

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75891134/html-internal-style-not-used-when-sent-to-email/75895378#75895378